# Suggest a professional way to say this statement

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

A news reporter responded to a question as below:

> We have no idea about this.

I am not sure how correct this statement is in a professional environment.

Can someone please suggest if there is a better way to say this statement.

Comment: Without any further context or comment, I don't see how this sentence is "unprofessional" in its current form.

Comment: "It wasn't me!"

Answer (score 1):

If by "professional" you mean *how would this statement be cast in a political setting, avoiding the impression that any commitments are made or failure is admitted?*, you could go for something like

> I'm afraid that the information available to us at the current time may prove insufficient to formulate an official statement regarding our point of view on this subject; I can, however assure you that we are working on thoroughly investigating this matter as we speak.

If by "professional" you mean *clear*, *concise*, *to-the-point* and *honest*, the original statement is much better though.

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks context, and the reporter's allegedly informal remark could be a response in multiple scenarios.

Off the top of my head, these sound more professional, depending on the context:

> We are not aware of that/this.
>
> We were not made aware of that/this.
>
> We do not have that/this information.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly unprofessional about it. It's hard to judge without more context, but it's possible that even with such context it would still be ambiguous between two or more of:

> We had no idea this was happening
>
> We have no idea what to do about this
>
> We aren't familiar with this issue
>
> We don't have expertise/knowledge/experience in this topic

If so changing to the one that more precisely fits the bill (or something again if none of them do) may well be an improvement.